# Missing value for required argument 0 - RPC

Tags: web3.py, python, json-rpc, bsc

I am trying to send 2 transactions in one block using bnb48.club api. The problem is that I keep getting the error

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":48,"error":{"code":-32602,"message":"missing value for required argument 0"}}

My code:

```
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
}

data_a = {"id": 48,
          "jsonrpc": "2.0",
          "method": "eth_sendPuissant",
          "txs": str(txRaw),
          "maxTimestamp": time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()) + 60,
          "acceptReverting": []
}


a = requests.post('https://puissant-bsc.bnb48.club/', json=data_a, headers=headers)
```

txRaw has 2 signed bnb txn.

bnb48 docs: https://docs.bnb48.club/v/zhong-wen/buidl/infrastructure/bsc-validator/enhancedrpc/puissant-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to pass a params array with those values in the order given in the documentation. That's how all Etheruem RPC calls are made: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/.